# Инвалидация ссылок в векторе при добавлении новых элементов

Tags: c++

Функция принимает указатель на int. Можно ли использовать её так? Сомнения возникают, потому что может произости переаллокация и ссылки будут неверными. Или я неправильно понимаю? Если правильно, то как организовать подобное поведение без ошибок?

```
std::vector<int> elements{1,2,3,4,5};
while (true) {
 for (std::size_t i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
  foo(&(elements[i]));
 }

 // добавление новых элементов в вектор, но не удаление предыдущих
 elements.insert({6,7,8});
}
```

Comment: elements.insert({6,7,8}); неправильно, нужно  указать куда вставить:  elements.insert(elements.end(), {6, 7, 8})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваша функция `foo` не пытается "запоминать" полученный указатель для долгосрочного хранения и последующего использования где-то еще, то никаких проблем в вашем коде нет. Ваша переаллокация делается уже после того, как функция `foo` отработала. В представленном коде во время работы `foo` никакой переаллокации произойти не может.